# Android run service invisibly and unkillably.

Tags: android, service, task, daemon

I'm working for a company that's trying to run an application on it's phones. The application needs to in a way that can't be killed by a task manager and starts at boot. Is there any way to do this? Possibly through loading a custom rom?

Comment: I am afraid workers is still able to root their devices and kill task.  And realy, is not good to spy workers.

Comment: I understand they can root it, but this is a part of their job responsibility to carry this phone and keep this task running. We're expecting to have people that would kill the task on accident with many of the task killers out there. We're trying to simplify the process of keeping this running even if they unknowingly try to kill it.

Comment: For the record, this is a device we are lending them with full knowledge that this is running. Not their own personal device.

Comment: As an added tidbit, I know this should be doable.  The Hotmail app for Android somehow manages to revive itself after being killed.  Possibly has some type of scheduled task or some such.  Another option would be to have two separate apps, where one just monitors the main app and revives it if it gets killed, and the main app returns the favor to the monitor.

Comment: @RossAiken: task killer is able to kill both apps

Comment: The app I had in mind that was capable of doing this was actually Avast. I had several ideas on how to do this. First I looked into spawning a service, or a thread. But apparently both of those are killed when the main processess is killed (I'm currently in the process of trying a modified version of this attempt. Possibly running it in a system thread?) Then I looked into an onExit call that could simply revive the program, but that doesn't seem to exist in android. Then I looked into setting a flag that would make it invisible to the task killers. I haven't found one.